# how to send email with multiple Apostrophe & quotation mark in body of email

Tags: php, email

i have email template which consist of html tags like this

```
$mail->Body = '<td style="color: #848484; font-size: 14px; font-family: Calibri, 
sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; line-height: 18px; border-collapse: collapse;" 
align="left">Copyright (C) 2016 example All rights reserved.</td>';
```

Now if i change 'Open Sans' into "Open Sans" fonts become messy in look & there are more tags in template which consist of Apostrophe

what could be the best way of sending this email template without getting any error

Comment: The best way would be to read up on proper string escaping.

Comment: what you have there should have been throwing you parse errors, but didn't bother setting up your server to catch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you delimit a string literal with single-quotes, and want to use single-quotes inside the string content, you need to escape them with a backslash:

```
$mail->Body = '<td style="color: #848484; font-size: 14px; font-family: Calibri, 
sans-serif, \'Open Sans\'; line-height: 18px; border-collapse: collapse;" 
align="left">Copyright (C) 2016 example All rights reserved.</td>';
```

Same thing with double-quotes instead:

```
$mail->Body = "<td style=\"color: #848484; font-size: 14px; font-family: Calibri, 
sans-serif, 'Open Sans'; line-height: 18px; border-collapse: collapse;\" 
align=\"left\">Copyright (C) 2016 example All rights reserved.</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should Use htmlspecialchars [HTML Special Chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)